# Changing a bool to a value other than 0 or 1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    bool b;

    // Set b to 123
    char *p = (char*)&b;
    *p = 123;

    // Check if b is considered to be true
    if (b == true) printf("b is true");

    return 0;
}
```

`b` is not considered to be `true`, so what does `true` means exactly, is `true` equals to `1`?

---

***Edit:*** Forgot to say that I'm using Visual C++.

Comment: Well, under gcc/g++: bool is true.

Comment: It's probably undefined behavior.

Comment: EDIT: I believe what I said was misleading-- I think @KeithThompson is far more correct than I.

Comment: @DrewDormann: `char*` is an exception to the strict aliasing rule. Of course, the OP is getting lucky here as `bool` is actually an int in all implementations I've seen.

Comment: @DrewDormann: No problem.  C keeps even veterans entertained at times.  I still refer to this once in a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: Do note that a `bool` can be any size, depending on the compiler and platform. It's not necessarily one byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool b;

// Set b to 123
char *p = (char*)&b;
*p = 123;
```

The C++ Standard leaves it unspecified how `bool` are stored... e.g. entirely legal for one compiler to use one byte and another to use four.  Further, one compiler might store say `0` for `false` and all-bits-on for `true` and another `0` and `1` or whatever other values.  All that mattered is that when used in a boolean context the logic works correctly, and that when converted to or from an `int`:

- `int(b)` is `1` if `b` is `true`, and `0` if `b` is `false`, and
- `bool(n)` is `true` if-and-only-if `n` was not `0`.

Because of this, the character at the lowest memory address in the `bool` representation may or may not be consulted when testing the value of the boolean: it could be one compiler's generated code uses a four-byte `int` that is read then has only the least significant bit or byte tested, which - depending on endianness - may not have been touched by the `*p = 123`.  Similarly, the compiler might read the value into a signed integer register and test for negativeness (expecting an all-bits-on value when `true`), which could also fail even if `*p = 123` had written to the only or most significant byte.

Consequently - even if there was nothing else at play - the line below might not report "b is true"...

```
// Check if b is considered to be true
if (b == true) printf("b is true");
```

...but that test is further flawed by...

- possibly reading from other bytes in the `bool` representation that haven't been initialised (uninitialised memory reads have undefined behaviour)
- fiddling with the `bool` value alone inherently has "undefined behaviour"; in terms of "binary writing" to the `bool`'s memory, only a full byte-for-byte copy from another properly initialised `bool` is guaranteed to leave this `bool` is a usable state.

Comment: Didn't know that C++11 made that change, +1.

Comment: @EdS. yikes - my mistake - memory playing tricks.  It's the new enum features that default to `int` and allow explicit sizing.  Corrected the answer above.  Cheers.

Comment: Well that makes sense; I couldn't find it in the spec :)  Still, +1

Answer (score 1):

C++11 says (3.9 "Types" [basic.types]):

> The value representation of an object is the set of bits that hold the
>   value of type T. For trivially copyable types, the value
>   representation is a set of bits in the object representation that
>   determines a value, which is one discrete element of an
>   implementation-defined set of values

And (3.9.1 "Fundamental types" [basic.fundamental]):

> For character types, all bits of the object representation participate
>   in the value representation. For unsigned character types, all
>   possible bit patterns of the value representation represent numbers.
>   **These requirements do not hold for other types**.
>
> ...
>
> Values of type bool are either true or false

And finally, 5 "Expressions" [expr] says:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or **not in the range of representable values** for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

What is happening is that when you write the value 123 to the memory that the `bool` object occupies (through the `char* p`), you're writing something that can't be represented in the `bool` object's 'value representation'.  So when you subsequently access that object through the lvalue `b` the program exhibits undefined behavior and you have a `bool` object that is neither `true` nor `false`.

And to answer your question about what the value of `true` is: the standard never actually specifies.  It does specify that the `true` is one of the two values a `bool` type can represent (the other being `false` of course).  The standard also specifies that `true` readily converts to 1 and vice versa, 1 readily converts to `true`. These conversion happen so naturally and easily that I think that nearly everyone considers `true` to have the value 1.

One thing to remember is that nearly any non-zero integral value will readily convert to `true` - not just 1. However that doesn't happen in your example for the value 123 because in that expression it is being written to an lvalue with `char` type so no conversion to `bool` occurs.

Comment: I don't think that quote from [expr] covers this case; it's talking about things like integer overflow

Answer (score 0):

`true` means `1`

But 123 is also considered as  true (Generally all  integers except zero)

if you say

```
if (b) printf("b is true");
```

you must get the output `b is true`

Comment: accepted!, I myself usually use positive ints for true. Thanks